# data loss in multiple window aggregations in apache flink using KeyedProcessFunction implementation

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to compute aggregations in flink using KeyedProcessFunction, where I am computing hour aggregates, and using the results to compute the daily aggregates. The timer fires at end of hour for the last hour of day, and the timer for the day fires at the same moment, resulting in the last hour output not ready for day input and thus data loss.
How do we avoid data loss of the last hour aggregate counts in the daily aggregates?

Comment: Maybe you can fire the daily aggregate using a count based trigger? When you've got 24 hourly aggregates, fire the daily one.

Comment: Can you use event time triggering, rather than processing time?